# I am trying to push a directory to a server using rsync. What is wrong with this command?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I am trying to push a directory to a server using rsync. What is wrong with this command?

Hello,

I am trying to push a directory to my computer running SSH on port 2222. See below. I get a connection refused error. Any idea how I can make this work?

rsync --update -P -r -v -e ssh -p $2222 /home/pi/rsynctest root@192.168.43.168:/root/rsynctest/

Vesa

Platform: Debian custom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote ssh-with-port as a **single argument** like `-e 'ssh -p 2222'` or `-e "ssh -p 2222"`. What you wrote specifies `ssh` as the argument to the `-e` option then the `-p` option *to rsync* (same as `--perms`) followed by a probably spurious filename, which would give an error if connection (and authentication) succeeded.

Do not use `$2222`. That would not specify the number 2222; in singlequotes it would specify the actual string `$2222` which is not a number, in doublequotes it would expand to the second positional parameter of your shell, which is probably an empty string, followed by `222`.

**Alternatively**, as the man page says, you can **use the ssh config file** (normally) `.ssh/ssh_config` to specify the port automatically (for all, one, or some hosts). That also applies to other things you do that use ssh, such as `scp sftp` and of course `ssh`, which is probably desirable here.

Comment: That seems like a step closer to the solution. At least I am prompted to input the password of the SSH server now. But then I get this error message: rsync: command not found. I have rsync on the client only. Do I need to install rsync on the SSH server as well?

Comment: Answering myself: yes rsync seems to be required both on the server and the client. Everything seems to be working now, but I will update again if I run into some issues during testing.